# Error when compiling OpenCV for Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, cmake

In order to use OpenCV in Qt, I have to compile it with MinGW by cmake.

Software are the following:

- Qt 5.4.0
- Opencv 2.4.11
- CMake 3.2.2
- MinGW version unknown, GCC 4.8.1

A fatal error occurred when I make file and I have no idea how to solve it at all.

```
[ 29%] Automatic moc for target opencv_highgui
Generating moc_window_QT.cpp
Exit code 0xc000007b

AUTOGEN: error: process for C:/opencvbuild/modules/highgui/moc_window_QT.cpp failed:
Exit code 0xc000007b

moc failed...
modules\highgui\CMakeFiles\opencv_highgui_automoc.dir\build.make:48: recipe for target 'modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui_automoc' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui_automoc] Error 1

CMakeFiles\Makefile2:2066: recipe for target 'modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui_automoc.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui_automoc.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:145: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

These messages are shown in cmd.

Then I revised CMakeLists.txt, SET(CMAKE_AUTOMOC OFF)

```
modules\highgui\CMakeFiles\opencv_highgui_automoc.dir\build.make:64: recipe for target 'modules/highgui/qrc_window_QT.cpp' failed
```

Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: I do not think either CMake warning has anything to do with the moc failure.

Comment: But they just point to the same directory, is that coincidence?

Comment: And I'm also curious about why my command CMAKE_POLICY(SET CMP0020 NEW)  didn't work.

Comment: Could it be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351350/qt-moc-exe-not-generating-moc-file or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351350/qt-moc-exe-not-generating-moc-file ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I solved all the warnings by editting CMakeFile in source directory. There is no error or warning  when configuring or generating. But the problem still exists when making file.

Answer (score 0):

2 items to try.

1. Try running `make` with `VERBOSE=1` to increase the output on the makefile.  That should give you a better idea of what is wrong.
2. Try running with `cmake-gui`, then turn on advanced mode to check out what CMake found for the different Qt5 dependencies.  On Mac, I install the latest Qt to my home directory, causing me to have to manually set variables.  This is what it looks like for me.

[image]

[image]

Hopefully this provides some useful information.

Comment: I did manually set variables like Fig.1, but I don't see so many variables in Fig.2.

Comment: make with VERBOSE=1 it points to the file /source/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.qrc

Comment: ***but I don't see so many variables in Fig.2.*** Did you enable the advanced and grouped check boxes in cmake-gui?

Comment: Yes.  I had to check those.